# Can I get help figuring out this?

Tags: java, input, output, newline, removing-whitespace

When i run my code, I get an error in mimir (idk if you guys know about it but is a platform that teachers use to check the test cases of the code that you submit) saying that I a have a whitespace that shouldn't be there (check image).

[image: error in my code]
1.) how can i fix that regarding my code.

and another issue which it drove me crazy is,
how can I make it so that when I enter a letter, In this case it was inputted 'f' (check the image) to display the "enter two integers:" just like the imagine. I tried different types of loops and changing the layout but i never got it to be correct.
[image: output of how its supposed to be]

p.d. Yes, this was a homework and was due yesterday. Even though i got a good grade on it, it still bugged me that I couldn't figure out these two things out.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MathTeacher {


  public static int addNumbers(int n1, int n2){
    int add = n1+n2;
    return add;
  }

  public static int subtractNumbers(int n1, int n2){
    int subs = n1-n2;
    return subs;
  }

  public static int multiplyNumbers(int n1, int n2){
    int mulp = n1*n2;
    return mulp;
  }

  public static int divideNumbers(int n1, int n2){
    int div = n1/n2;
    return div;
  }

  private static int getIntFromUser(Scanner scan) {
    int x;
    while (true) {
      try {
        x = scan.nextInt();
        break;
      } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        scan.next();
      }
    }
    return x;
  }
  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to *Mental Math Practice* where you can test your addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division.");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter two integers: ");
    String typeQuit= "";
    do {
      int choices;

      int n1 = getIntFromUser(scanner);
      int n2 = getIntFromUser(scanner);
      System.out.println("Enter 1 to add the two numbers.");
      System.out.println("Enter 2 to subtract the second number from the first number.");
      System.out.println("Enter 3 to multiply the two numbers.");
      System.out.println("Enter 4 to divide the first number by the second number.");

      choices = scanner.nextInt();
      switch (choices) {
        case 1: {
          int add = addNumbers(n1, n2);
          System.out.println(add);
          break;
        }
        case 2: {

          int sub = subtractNumbers(n1, n2);
          System.out.println(sub);
          break;
        }
        case 3: {

          int mulp = multiplyNumbers(n1, n2);
          System.out.println(mulp);
          break;
        }
        case 4: {

          int div = divideNumbers(n1, n2);
          System.out.println(div);
          break;
        }

      }
      System.out.println("Enter 'Quit' to end the program.");
      typeQuit = scanner.next();
    } while(!typeQuit.equals("Quit"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Try changing `System.out.println("Enter two integers: ");` to `System.out.println("Enter two integers:");` :/

Comment: @MadProgrammer has the first issue covered. You were literally writing out an extra space. Automated testing in this case was harsh :P For the second issue, you'll want to add some logic to code that detects a input that isn't an integer and writes out your message to the user. Perhaps something in `getIntFromUser`. You could potentially handle it in the `InputMismatchException` catch block, but it's usually best practice to avoid exceptions, so you'd probably want to read the user input as a string and use a parsing method relevant to the framework you're on. `TryParse` or whatnot.